# Why isn't this swap program working in C?

Tags: c, swap

I'm completely new to C and I'm trying to create a basic swap program, can someone please explain why the code below isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap (int *p1, int *p2);
    int *temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;

int main ()
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;
    int *p1 = &x, *p2 = &y;
    swap (p1, p2);

    printf ("x: %d, y: %d\n", x, y);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and you will see the problem.

Comment: `temp` should just be an `int`, not an `int*`

Comment: Also, you have to write an actual function with `{ }`...

Comment: Please post real code, this code does not compile.

Comment: Your code should work as expected, You just need to correct the function as what @Lundin says.

Comment: @Gaurav how can that code work as expected, when it doesn't even compile?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Updated my comment! ;-)

Comment: Ok I'll add that, thanks.

Comment: @Gaurav your comment still claims the code works...

Comment: @Ben unrelated to your problem, but instead of  `int *p1 = &x, *p2 = &y;
  swap(p1, p2);` you can simple write `swap(&x, &y);`. You don't need `p1` and `p2` at all.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks, I'll use that from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The void is a sub-process, it must be enclosed in braces and must not end in a semicolon.
on the other hand as the community says `int * temp = * p1;` is a constaint violation, it must be `int temp = * p1;`

Nor was exchanging values, it showed only as when they were entered.

Finally, the main returns an `int`, you must specify that you return a 0, that is done with `return 0;`

The whole program would be like that

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap (int *p1, int *p2){
    int temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}

int main ()
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;
    swap (p1, p2);

    printf ("x: %d, y: %d\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

`int *temp = *p1;` will not compile (this is a *constraint violation* and must result in a compiler diagnostic): you are assigning an `int` (other than 0) to a pointer type. And that's not allowed.

Write `int temp = *p1;`, fix the obvious typos in the `swap` function - give it a body! - and all will be well.

Comment: Undefined? The conversions back and forth is allowed

Comment: @StoryTeller: How sure are you of this? What if you have a 128 bit `int` and a 48 bit pointer, for example?

Comment: The problem is the lack of an explicit cast, that is a constraint violation. But integer to pointer and back business is perfectly well covered. Caveats and all.

Comment: `int *temp = *p1;` is a _constraint violation_ and must result in a compiler diagnostic.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Yes, that would be rippingly posh.